# When declaring a variable with an equation, what happens to the memory allocation?

Tags: java, variables, memory-management

I was wondering if declaring a variable with an equation will recall the equation every time I'll use the variable or just the result of the equation.

For example, I have a variable that is defined as the area of a circle of radius `radius`.

```
double radius = 0.5d;
double pi = 3.1415926535d;
double area = Math.pow(radius,2)*pi;
```

Will the area be defined as `pi*radius^2` or as 0.78539816337? In other words, will the computer do the calculations every time or only once and reuse that value?

If this writing forces the computer to repeat the calculations, how could I improve it? (The code will be doing billions of operations using variables declared like that)

Comment: is radius constant ?

Comment: They will all stay constant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It'll be calculated only once. Let's say you want to use `area` in the next line, so your code looks like:

```
double radius = 0.5d;
double pi = 3.1415926535d;
double area = Math.pow(radius,2)*pi;
double x = area;
```

Now let's examine the bytecode:

```
public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
   Code:
      0: ldc2_w         #2          // double 0.5d
      3: dstore_1
      4: ldc2_w         #4          // double 3.1415926535d
      7: dstore_3
      8: dload_1
      9: ldc2_w         #6          // double 2.0d
      12: invokestatic  #8         // Method java/lang/Math.pow:(DD)D
      15: dload_3
      16: dmul
      17: dstore        5
      19: dload         5
      21: dstore        7
      23: return
```

The value of `area` is stored in the line:

```
17: dstore        5
```

and when you want to use the variable `area`, it's simply loaded and not recalculated:

```
19: dload         5
```

Answer (score 0):

The expression on the right of the `=` sign is called an *initializer*, and it is executed when the declaration statement is executed.

This is defined in the Java Language Specification, [§14.4.2 Execution of Local Variable Declarations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.4.2):

> A local variable declaration statement is an executable statement. Every time it is executed, the declarators are processed in order from left to right. If a declarator has an initializer, **the initializer is evaluated and its value is assigned to the variable**.